# Vsftpd not displaying files and folder

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, chroot, vsftpd

I run `vsftpd: version 3.0.2` on Debian 8.
I have a folder `/home/vsftpd/$USER` which is mounted on an NFS.

`$USER` is replaced by the user name connected on the FTP.
Those users are authenticated against MySQL using `pam-mysql`.

All the users can connect to the FTP **BUT** none of them are able to see their files and folders.
I've tried `777` on their `$USER` folder and sub-folders but nothing.

I managed to have a file displayed but I don't know how/why. But I was unable to download the file:

```
Status: Starting download of /a
Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (**.**.**.**,24,163).
Command:    RETR a
Response:   550 Failed to open file.
Error:  Critical file transfer error
```

I have two issues: users connected to the FTP cannot see their files and folders and I'm unable to dowload a file.

Here is the `vsftpd.conf`

```
listen=YES

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES

write_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO

guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd

chroot_local_user=YES

max_clients=200
max_per_ip=4

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=6000
pasv_max_port=6800
pasv_address=**.**.**.**

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/***.com.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd/**.com.key
#user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_user_conf

local_root=/home/vsftpd/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
```

Logs for the file download error `/var/log/vsftpd.log`

```
FTP response: Client "91.177.204.148", "230 Login successful."
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP command: Client "***", "CWD /"
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP response: Client "***", "250 Directory successfully changed."
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP command: Client "***", "TYPE A"
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP response: Client "***", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP command: Client "***", "PASV"
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP response: Client "***", "227 Entering Passive Mode (52,58,132,46,23,207)."
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP command: Client "***", "RETR a"
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FTP response: Client "***", "550 Failed to open file."
Sun Dec 10 13:52:59 2017 [pid 14999] [*] FAIL DOWNLOAD: Client "***", "/a", 0.00Kbyte/sec
```

**EDIT**

I've added local_umask=022 (don't know if it is useful or not)

Comment: Look in your server log files they will likely have additional information on the 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved those two issues by setting the permissions to `0555` to folders and files (files should only have 0444).